# Axis2 Web service POST request not working in Linux - wrong number of arguments

Tags: soap, http-post, wso2, apache-axis

All,
I am working with `Axis2` Web services. The services are bundled as `.aar file` and deployed in `WSO2 Application Server(AS)`. I am able to deploy the generated .aar in WSO2 AS running in `Windows environment` as well as `Linux environment`.
The problem is,
When I try to access the POST service hosted in both the environment(Windows & Linux), I am `getting response in Windows while getting the following error in the Linux` environment.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:178)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
 at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
 at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-07-02 04:18:22,576] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  Error processing POST request for : /services/MyService/postRequest {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: wrong number of arguments
 at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:211)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
 at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
 at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:178)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
 ... 9 more.
```

The following are the input I have given:

```
URI:  

     https://localhost:8243/services/MyService/postRequest  

Input XML:  

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.sample.vijay.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:postRequest>
         <ser:paramOne>Hello</ser:paramOne>
         <ser:paramTwo>All</ser:paramTwo>
         <ser:paramThree>This is POST request</ser:paramThree>
      </ser:postRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I try to access the above service using rest client in `Windows machine`(Chrome Browser -> cREST plugin), it returns me expected result.
But when I try the same request with same URI in `Linux environment`(host address alone changed to Linux IP), ended up in above error(Wondering What might be the problem).

```
Do I need to change any configuration in Linux machine or WSO2 Application Server in Linux machine?
```

**Note:**
When I change the URI to `https://localhost:8243/services/MyService`, its working fine in Linux as well as Windows. But my requirement is to have the web method name(`/postRequest here`) in the URI.
Please help me resolving this strange issue.
Thanks in Advance.

**Edit:**

My services.xml is:

```
<serviceGroup name="AxisServices">
    <service name="MyService">
        <description>
            Please Type your service description here
        </description>
        <messageReceivers>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
                class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"></messageReceiver>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
                class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"></messageReceiver>
        </messageReceivers>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.vijay.sample.service.MyService</parameter>
    </service>
```

My Java class:

```
package com.vijay.sample.service;

public class MyService {

    public String postRequest(String paramOne, String paramTwo, String paramThree) {

        // Logic here
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just asking this to confirm. As I understand, you have two separate instances running on Windows and Linux. Have you deployed the same aar file in both instances? Could you also please let me know the WSO2 Application Server version?

Comment: Yes, I am running 2 different instances with same .aar file. I have installed ESB and added Application Server feature to it. My ESB version is 4.6.0 and repository used for adding feature is http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following URI to access the service

```
http://localhost:9763/services/MyService/postRequest
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:8243/services/MyService/postRequest
```

Comment: Hi Chanaka, Thanks for the reply. The URI that u mentioned above are working fine in Windows environment but throwing error in Linux environment. That's where I am stuck up. Kindly let me know if any changes needed on server or some other place.

Comment: Hi Vijay, Can you share your configuration files. It is strange that it is not working in linux since we are testing all the things in linux environment.

Comment: Hi Chanaka, I have included my services.xml and Java class above (Below "Edit"). Please let me know if further information needed. And one note: When I published the above service to cloud gateway, it works as expected. i.e, When I access my service like http://localhost:9763/services/MyService/postRequest, it works fine.